# trouble on playing mp3 with pyglet module

Tags: python

I have installed AVbin10 in my computer(os windows7),As i running my program as the error comming.The error is “IOError Integer divided by zero”

```
Import pyglet 
pyglet.lib.load_library (‘c:\\user\\administrator\\desktop\\avbin64’)
pyglet.have_avbin=True
music=pyglet.media.load (‘c:\\user\\administrator\\desktop\\1.mp3’)
music.play ()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Can you give the full traceback of the exception? Also, your code seems to have had its formatting messed up as you were posting it. You have "fancy" quotation marks instead of regular ones, and `import` is inappropriately capitalized. Making your code an [mcve] is a good idea!

Comment: Thank you!I solved the problem.It is the AVbin version bugs which fixed in AVbin 11.